# Jumping from paired symbols in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

Is it possible in TeXstudio to jump cursor from space between two paired symbols like brackets, dollar signs (when typing math formula) etc. directly to the next position after second paired symbol using some shortcut. For example, usually I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, type some formula between two $ and then press <kbd>→</kbd> twice. Does some better way exist ?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of "better" way you are looking for. Certainly some keypress has to be registered for TXS to recognize you are done typing the math stuff and "want to get out of the $$ env". If not the arrow key, then write a macro to skip out of the $$ env and bind it to some keyboard combination. In this case then, I don't see it being too much of a  time-saver anyway..

Comment: I think I search for something like "complete current statement" combination, which is present in many IDEs (e.g. in PyCharm it is Ctrl+Shift+Enter. For example, if I type ( " and some text, and then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. IDE closes " ) and move caret to the next line. As for me, it's more useful than press arrow key two or more times. I'll think about macro, thanks.